# why is my header not going all the way across in portrait?

Tags: html, css, header

i can't figure out why is my header not going all the way across and i'd like some help with it

Here's the code for the header class in css

```
.header {padding-top:25px;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 display:block;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 background-color: rgb(64, 128, 141);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 1px 
 rgb(199, 199, 199);
}
```

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/don0ts/pen/dKxmqY
The page: www.peercd.com
Google pagespeed test so you can check how it looks on portrait from your computer: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.peercd.com&tab=mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the `width` set to cards in css causing the page to overflow.
Just set the width to 100% to occupy the available width instead on flowing out.

Here is updated codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajyMMJ.

Just curious why not using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Set the image-size, card1 and card2 to 'width=100%'.
You're forcing the width of them.